# Do women rate 80% of men as "below average looking"?

Tags: sexuality, gender

From Reddit's "Today I Learned" section:

[TIL Women find 80% of men below-average looking - according to research based on OkCupid's 7 million users](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/135099/til_women_find_80_of_men_belowaverage_looking/).

1. Is this an accurate summary of OKCupid's research?
2. Is OKCupid's research valid? (other than the obvious criticism that their data has a built in selction bias of being confined to OKCupid userbase).
3. Is that conclusion corroborated by other research?

A more general form of the claim is discussed [here](http://www.hookingupsmart.com/2010/09/14/hookinguprealities/sex-and-the-pareto-principle/) (basically, that Pareto principle applies to dating).

Comment: Couldn't quite figure out how to tag this, feel free to retag

Comment: Tangentially, that same link showed that men's ratings were a bell  shaped symmetrical curve with what looked like normal(ish) distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure the first question is relevant since they provide a link to OkCupid's report.

Comment: I didn't have time to research #3 in detail, but bumped into purported Tinder statistics that seems very close (Women swipe right 15% of time, men 50% - vs OKCupid's ~20%/50%). Not really sure how methodologically sound Tinder swipe counts are.

Comment: Maybe good-looking men don't use OKCupid, because they can easily get dates without it??

Comment: @GEdgar - given general dating dynamics, that statement is probably even more applicable to women than men (there's generally less women than men on such sites iirc)

Comment: One question to ask is whether "looks" are normally distributed.  That is, there are relatively few good-looking people, but they are very good looking, so they skew the average.

Comment: @sklivvz  - sorry, I rolled back your subject line edit - (1) the general non-OKCupid claim can be found (though rooted in link to that research) easily; (2) my main subj-question is #3, asking for corroborating research. I only ask #1 and #2 in the unlikely case the headline was misleading or OKC results completely wrong somehow (both of which seem unlikely)

Comment: Please add a relevant quote then.

Comment: @Sklivvz - here's representative claim citing tinder: http://theformerfatkid.net/why-most-men-dont-get-laid-on-tinder/.

Comment: Here's a study that might be relevant - there is greater consensus among men about what is "attractive" : [Rating Attractiveness: Consensus Among Men, Not Women, Study Finds](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/06/090626153511.htm)

Comment: Here's another [How Tinder “Feedback Loop” Forces Men and Women into Extreme Strategies](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/601909/how-tinder-feedback-loop-forces-men-and-women-into-extreme-strategies/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see the original article at OkCupid:
[Your Looks and Your Inbox, How men and women perceive attractiveness](https://theblog.okcupid.com/your-looks-and-your-inbox-8715c0f1561e)

As to the specific questions :

1. Seems to be an accurate description
2. Depends on the definition of valid - the methodology seems to support the narrow
   claims, but because of selection bias and other factors, not
   necessarily strong enough to support drawing broader conclusions.
3. I would go with a
   weak yes here, there is some psychological research in the area,
   some of which points to celebrity culture and other things
   distorting the standard, but there doesn't seem to be something definitive.

Comment: Please add the relevant quotes from that article.

Comment: Can you provide references to the research mentioned in your answer to #3?

Comment: See for example https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1014815725852?LI=true, there is a lot of research in the area

Comment: The OkCupid rates *photos* of men. It doesn't account for men having poorer photos.